# iPhone: delete button doesn't function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delete-row

I'm a new iPhone application developer. My application doesn't function when I press the Delete button from simulator in iPhone. I have copied some code from my project here. I hope I can solve the bug if possible. I tired to find this problem already, hope can help me solve.

my code here.

FirstPage.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface FirstPage : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>{
    IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;
    IBOutlet UITextField *eventText;
    IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;
    NSMutableArray *Array;
    NSArray *notificationArray;

    UILocalNotification *notif;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *eventText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;
- (IBAction) scheduleAlarm:(id) sender;
//add,delete.edit table

-(IBAction)EditTable:(id)sender;


@end
```

N my FirstPage.m at here.

```
  #import "FirstPage.h"


@implementation FirstPage
@synthesize datePicker, eventText,tableview;
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.tableview reloadData];
}
- (IBAction) scheduleAlarm:(id) sender {
    [eventText resignFirstResponder];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

    // Get the current date
    NSDate *pickerDate = [self.datePicker date];

    // Break the date up into components
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit ) 
                                                   fromDate:pickerDate];
    NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit  ) 
                                                   fromDate:pickerDate];

    // Set up the fire time
    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComps setDay:[dateComponents day]];
    [dateComps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
    [dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];
    [dateComps setHour:[timeComponents hour]];
    // Notification will fire in one minute
    [dateComps setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];
//  [dateComps setSecond:[timeComponents second]];
    NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];
    [dateComps release];

    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotif == nil)
        return;
    localNotif.fireDate = itemDate;
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    // Notification details
    localNotif.alertBody = [eventText text];
    // Set the action button
    localNotif.alertAction = @"View";

    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

    // Specify custom data for the notification
    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"someValue" forKey:@"someKey"];
    localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;

    // Schedule the notification
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
    [localNotif release];

    [self.tableview reloadData];

}
// The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
/*
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization.
    }
    return self;
}
*/
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField { 
    [eventText resignFirstResponder]; 
    return YES; 
} 

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
//Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    //notificationArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:Array];
    Array = [notificationArray mutableCopy];
    eventText.delegate = self; 
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    int count = [Array count];
    if(self.editing) {
        count++;
        //return [[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotifications];
        return count;
    }else {
        return [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] count];
    }




}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    notificationArray = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
//  notificationArray = Array;
//  [notificationArray mutableCopy];
    notif = [notificationArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell.textLabel setText:notif.alertBody];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[notif.fireDate description]];

    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)DeleteButtonAction:(id)sender
{
//  [Array removeLastObject];
    [Array removeLastObject];
    NSLog(@"testing in delete button...");
    //[tableview reloadData];
}

- (IBAction) EditTable:(id)sender
{
    if(self.editing)
    {
        [super setEditing:NO animated:NO]; 
        [tableview setEditing:NO animated:NO];
    //  [tableview reloadData];
    //  [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Edit"];
    //  [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain];
    }
    else
    {
        [super setEditing:YES animated:YES]; 
        [tableview setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    //  [tableview reloadData];
    //  [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Done"];
    //  [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone];
    }
}

// The editing style for a row is the kind of button displayed to the left of the cell when in editing mode.
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    // No editing style if not editing or the index path is nil.
    if (self.editing == NO || !indexPath) return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    // Determine the editing style based on whether the cell is a placeholder for adding content or already 
    // existing content. Existing content can be deleted.    

        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;

}

// Update the data model according to edit actions delete or insert.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {
    //  [Array removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath indexAtPosition:1]];
        [Array removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //  [tableview deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];

        NSLog(@"at delete button mah?...");
        [tableview reloadData];
    } 
}

#pragma mark Row reordering
// Determine whether a given row is eligible for reordering or not.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}
// Process the row move. This means updating the data model to correct the item indices.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath 
      toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath 
{
    NSString *item = [[Array objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row] retain];
    [Array removeObject:item];
    [Array insertObject:item atIndex:toIndexPath.row];
    [item release];
}


/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    datePicker = nil;
    tableview = nil;
    eventText = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by 'does not function'. It's hard to help without knowing what the problem is - any relevant error message would be helpful.

Comment: in my table view i have some data row.then when i click the delete button will not function.

Comment: by 'not function', do you mean that the delete button doesn't do anything, or that the whole app crashes?

Comment: are you using Interface Builder? Have you connected up the buttons outlets and delegates from IB to your code?

Comment: sorry for late reply,the delete button doesn't do anything,yup i using Interface Builder,i have connected up the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer from the fact's presented by the question but it looks to me like you haven't created a IBOutlet for the delete button in your code and you haven't set it and its delegate in IB.

Comment: Thanks to you reply,i will check again.